# Convert .HEIC sequence to animated .GIF using Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, animated-gif, heic

I've managed to install Imagemagick 7 on my server and set-up the appropriate PHP module in order to work with HEIC and WebP files using Imagick.

I can convert these files easily to other formats like PNG or JPEG without any problems.

Now, I try to convert a HEIC sequence ([original file](https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any/blob/master/demo/3.heic?raw=true)) to GIF, but the result is imperfect.

First off all, it seems, that Imagick isn't able to determine the delay between every image. This results in a lightning fast animation. So for now, I've hardcoded a delay of 40 ticks using [Imagick::setImageDelay](https://www.php.net/manual/imagick.setimagedelay.php). I'm not sure, if I'm missing something, or if Imagick/Imagemagick isn't able to do this on HEIC sequences.

The next problem I'm experiencing is, that Imagick can't handle the original image dimensions properly. To get around this, I have to get the original image's dimensions and perform [Imagick::cropImage](https://www.php.net/manual/imagick.cropimage.php) and [Imagick::thumbnailImage](https://www.php.net/manual/imagick.thumbnailimage.php) on every frame, before I finalize it with [Imagick::setImagePage](https://www.php.net/manual/de/imagick.setimagepage.php).

However, my biggest problem for now is, that the result has a broken, first frame:

[image: broken first frame]

So the final (broken) result looks like this:

[image: final broken result]

While the expected result (generated by [heic2any](https://alexcorvi.github.io/heic2any/)) is:

[image: heic2any result]

The (simplified) code I am using:

```php
<?php
if (!in_array('HEIC', \Imagick::queryFormats("HEI*"))) {
    throw new \Exception('Unsupported format');
}

$sourceFile = __DIR__ . '/3.heic';
$targetFile = __DIR__ . '/3.gif';

if (!file_exists($sourceFile)) {
    try {
        $content = file_get_contents('https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any/blob/master/demo/' . basename($sourceFile) . '?raw=true');

        if ($content === false) {
            throw new \Exception('Unable to download source file.');
        }

        file_put_contents($sourceFile, $content);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception('Unable to download source file: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    if (!file_exists($sourceFile)) {
        throw new \Exception('Cannot find source file.');
    }
}

$im = new \Imagick($sourceFile);
$width = $im->getImageWidth();
$height = $im->getImageHeight();
$im = $im->coalesceImages();

foreach ($im as $frame) {
    $im->setImageDelay(40);

    $frame->cropImage($width, $height, 0, 0);
    $frame->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
    $frame->setImagePage($width, $height, 0, 0);
}

$im = $im->deconstructImages();
$im->writeImages($targetFile, true);

echo 'Size: ' . $width . 'x' . $height . '<br />Result:<br /><br /><img src="' . basename($targetFile) . '?v=' . time() . '" alt="" />';
```

So my questions are:

- Where does the 1st frame come from?
- How can I avoid it?
- Is there anything to optimize the conversion (code)?

UPDATE:

There's another .HEIC sequence to play with ([click](https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any/blob/master/demo/15.heic?raw=true)) and this one can be converted without problems:

[image: result]

UPDATE:

Even conversion services like [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/heic-to-gif) can't handle the image correctly and producing GIF animations like this:

[image: whoops]

Comment: I am not an expert on Imagick. But the first odd frame is likely what was left in memory for the animation background. You need to set the disposal method. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedispose.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose. To optimize, you need to use the equivalent of -layers optimize. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#frame_opt and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.optimizeimagelayers.php

Comment: Tried that to use/combine both methods, but they don't have any visible effect. The problem remains. However, I've added another conversion result, that doesn't have these problems.

Comment: I suggest you try using Imagemagick command line and test your command there. I do not have heic installed, so cannot test that conversion. I suggest starting with converting your heic images to PNG or JPG. Then make a gif animation from that. See if you can set the frame disposal such that it creates a good animation. If that works, then repeat with your heic images.

Comment: For example: `convert -dispose none -delay 50 frames_*.png -layers optimize test.gif` Try the different disposal methods.